# UICollectionViewCell Selection selects/highlights every 5 cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a horizontal collectionview with code to highlight/color the cell selected. It highlights the cell that was selected, but then every 5 cells after also get highlighted. Any idea what is going on?

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    for(int x = 0; x < [cellArray count]; x++){
        UICollectionViewCell *UnSelectedCell = [cellArray objectAtIndex:x];
        UnSelectedCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.5 blue:0.8 alpha:0.0];
    }
    UICollectionViewCell *SelectedCell = [cellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    SelectedCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.5 blue:0.8 alpha:1.0];
    cellSelected = indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"%i", cellSelected);

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That happens because cells are *reused* when you scroll. You have to store the "highlighted" status for all rows in your model (for example in an array or `NSMutableIndexSet`), and in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` set the background color of the cell according to the status for that row.

In `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` it should be sufficient to set the color of the newly selected
and the previously selected cell.

*Update:* If only *one* cell can be selected at a time, you just have to remember the
index path of the selected cell.

Declare a property `selectedIndexPath` for the currently highlighted row:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
```

In `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, unhighlight the previous cell, and highlight the new cell:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.selectedIndexPath != nil) {
        // deselect previously selected cell
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath];
        if (cell != nil) {
            // set default color for cell
        }
    }
    // Select newly selected cell:
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell != nil) {
        // set highlight color for cell
    }
    // Remember selection:
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

In `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, use the correct background color:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Identifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([self.selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath) {
        // set highlight color
    } else {
        // set default color
    }
}
```

Comment: I get that it happens because of reusable cells, but I kind of lost you after. How should I store the highlighted status? In didSelectItemAtIndexPath? Also, what do you mean in your last sentence?

Comment: @Spenciefy: Each time `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is called, you have to set the correct background color for the cell. Therefore you have to "remember" the status for *all rows*. That's what I meant with storing the status in an array or index set.

Comment: I see. So how do I assign selected or unselected in a indexset?

Comment: @Spenciefy: It seems that in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` you set the color for *all* cells (visible or invisible). That looks superfluous to me, because only two cells change their state.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused on how to use nsmutableindexset. Can you give a quick example?

Comment: @Spenciefy: If only *one* cell can be selected at a time, you don't need it and the solution is simpler. See updated answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40877/discussion-between-spenciefy-and-martin-r)

Answer (score 0):

I think you use reusable cell for collection - there is the point.
You shell to set default background color before reuse cell.

Comment: How would I set the default before the reuse cell; I highlight the cell when it is selected.